# How to start / stop / restart spring boot application using a web service

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application (JAR file), and I would like to launch it, stop it and restart it using a web service. How can I do that?.

Comment: If you want to *launch* the JAR file using a web service, then that service cannot be in the JAR file, which means it's a separate web service application. So what are you asking? Are to write a web service? How to run the JAR file from a Java program? What?

Comment: Yes I would like to execute (start, stop, restart) jar file using a java program.

Comment: You cannot start / stop / restart your app since they are standalone application. If you wrap them inside "container", then you can start / stop / restart a container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

**Workaround:** You need to use a "wrapper" which helps to start / stop / restart your sping-boot application as "Service".

For Unix OS:

You can setup your application launching with [supervisorctl](http://supervisord.org/running.html) command. [Third Party Applications and Libraries](http://supervisord.org/plugins.html) allows start / stop / restart with UI.

For Windows OS:

[Windows Service Wrapper](https://github.com/winsw/winsw)

For Docker container:

Add your spring-boot application as container. Also, add [portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) to manage docker images (included start / stop / restart spring-boot application).

Comment: Neither of those are web services for starting and stopping the runnable JAR file.

Comment: @Andreas Not agree with you. Supervisor is a wrapper to manage offline application and keep them running as service -> If you install any Web UI, you can start / stop / restart this services.

Comment: But your answer isn't to install a Web UI on top of the OS's service API, your answer is to just use the service API, which doesn't have web service remote access. In short, you didn't answer the question.